# Angular Redirecting to a specific element on the page without errors

Tags: html, angular, url-routing

I needed to add a span to my HTML with an ID to be able to go to it after clicking Reply button. I needed it only for the last element on the page. It works but I'm getting 2 errors in the console. Could anyone tell me what have I done wrong and how can I get rid of them?
[image: Errors]

```
<div class="comment">
<app-user-image></app-user-image>
<div class="position-relative d-inline-block flex-fill">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <div><strong>{{comment.author.name}} / {{comment.author.id}}</strong><span
            class="date">{{comment.created | krakenDateTime}}</span></div>
        <div class="actions">
            <button *ngIf="this.hateoas.supports(comment, 'update') && !edit"
                    type="button" class="bg-transparent border-0" title="Edit"
                    (click)="toggleEdit()"><i class="icon-kraken icon-kraken-edit"></i></button>
            <button *ngIf="this.hateoas.supports(comment, 'delete')"
                    type="button" class="bg-transparent border-0" title="Delete"
                    (click)="displayDeletionConfirmation()"><i class="icon-kraken icon-kraken-trash"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <textarea *ngIf="edit; else readonlyComment"
              #textarea
              class="d-block w-100"
              style="min-height: 7rem;"
              [rows]="rows()"
              [(ngModel)]="commentContent"></textarea>
    <ng-template #readonlyComment>
        <div [innerHTML]="commentContentHtml()"></div>
    </ng-template>
    <strong *ngIf="showReplyButton"
            class="reply-button"
            (click)="toggleReplyComponent()"><a href="#temporaryLastRow">Reply</a></strong>
</div>
```

here is the onInit method but I have not touched it

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.comment) {
        this.textArea.nativeElement.focus()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming `textArea` is a `@ViewChild` reading the `#textarea` ref

That `textarea` component is in an `ngIf`, so it won't be available during `ngOnInit`

Also, the `ngIf` specifically removes the `textarea` if the comment is displayed - so your logic seems a bit off

```html
<textarea *ngIf="edit; else readonlyComment" ...>
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know something about the second error?

Comment: Check your routes in the routeing module, you are trying to navigate to the non-existing route.